# $\ell_p\subsetneq\ell_r$ for $p<r$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $1\le p\le r <\infty$. Show that $\ell_p\subsetneq\ell_r$ for $p<r$.

So we have that

$$\ell_p = \left\{(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty:\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p<\infty\right\}$$
$$\ell_r = \left\{(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty:\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^r<\infty\right\}$$

Also, define the set of all sequences converging to zero as follows:

$$\mathcal{c}_0=\left\{(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty:\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_k = 0\right\}$$

Then one can show that $\ell_q \subsetneq \mathcal{c}_0$ for any $1\le q<\infty$. We want to show that if there is a sequence contained in $\ell_p$ then it is also in $\ell_r$, but not necessarily vice versa. A hint to this question suggests to use the integral convergence test.

Let $0<\varepsilon < 1$, then if $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty\in \ell_p$, there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies |x_N|^q<|x_N|^p \le \sum\limits_{i=N}^\infty |x_k|^p <\varepsilon $. Hence $\sum\limits_{i=N}^\infty |x_k|^q <\varepsilon$, so that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |x_k|^q <\infty$.

Now, I think that we could go the other way around by contradiction in order to prove that the inclusion is strict.

But I would think of the following approach:

Consider the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$, then $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\right|^r=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{n^{r/p}}\right|,$$

where $r/p>1$, thus the series converges. However,

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{n^{p/p}}\right|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|$$

does not converge. Hence, strict inclusion holds.

Please let me know if my proof is correct. At this time I don't think that the integral test is really needed.

Comment: Your proof is fine, I think the hint is that the "p-test" is often proven via the integral test.